# How can I add the number of products of a specific category to a CMS?

Tags: php, cms

I am creating a CMS page through Magento's admin page.

I want to display the number of products of a specific category. Any ideas of how can I achieve this?

Comment: please show your code?

Comment: CMS page or block? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own block, which gets a category ID as parameter, and then just implement the toHtml method like this:

return `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($passedId)->getProductCount()`